# how do you dynamically load a uitableview from a nsarray

Tags: uitableview

so i have a nsmutablearray that populates from a socket message.
problem is, when i call numberofrowsinsection on the uitableview, it will be 0, because it loads from the array.  the array has 0 objects, because the incomingMessage hasn't been received yet.

i observe this array in my appdelegate, when it changes, i call refreshData on the tableView, but it doesn't refresh.  how do you load a uitableview from a dynamic array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[tableView reloadData];` is how you refresh a table. How are you calling your NSArray?

This would be an example of how to add objects to a table from an array:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

for `numberOfRowsInSection` use: `[myArray count];`

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

after you add/remove stuff from the array.